# SQL - Find unique min value and associated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a set of data as below, showing the history of who has done what with a record. The unique identifier for each record is shown in 'ID' and 'Rec No' is the sequential number assigned to each interaction with the record.

```
ID  Rec No  Who Type
1   1   Bob New
1   2   Bob Open
1   3   Bob Assign
1   4   Sarah   Add
1   5   Bob Add
1   6   Bob Close
2   1   John    New
2   2   John    Open
2   3   John    Assign
2   4   Bob Assign
2   5   Sarah   Add
2   6   Sarah   Close
3   1   Sarah   New
3   2   Sarah   Open
3   3   Sarah   Assign
3   4   Sarah   Close
```

I need to find all of the 'Assign' operations. However where multiple 'Assign' are in a certain ID, I want to find the first one. I then also want to find the name of the person who did that.

So ultimately from the above date I would like the output to be-

```
Who Count (assign)
Bob 1
John    1
Sarah   1
```

The code I have at the moment is-

```
SELECT IH.WHO, Count(IH.ID)
FROM Table.INCIDENTS_H IH
WHERE (IH.TYPE = Assign)
GROUP BY IH.WHO
```

But this gives the output as-

```
Who Count (assign)
Bob 2
John    1
Sarah   1
```

As it is finding that Bob did an assign on ID 2, Rec No 4.

Any help would be appreciated. I am using MS SQL.

Comment: How do you know the output row is for the 1st bob/assign not the 2nd bob/assign? That is, if doesn't actually matter based on what you've given

Comment: You've killed my code layout edit!

Comment: @gbn - I rolled back to your edit since we were editing concurrently.  Assuming you were referring to someone else?

Comment: @JNK: OP edited after (revision 6)

Comment: @gbn I need to find the first assign in each ID. I can determine which is the first assign by recno as the one with the lowest value will be the first.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is what you are after:

```
select 
  who, count(id) 
from (
  select ID, Who, row_number() over (partition by ID order by Rec) [rownum]
  from Table.INCIDENTS_H IH
  WHERE (IH.TYPE = Assign)
) a
where rownum = 1
group by who
```

This should count only the first Assign (ordered by Rec) within each ID group.

Comment: I get an error saying check syntax to use near '(partition by ID order by Rec) [rownum]

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number to accomplish this

```
WITH INCIDENTS_H  as (
SELECT
1 as ID, 1 as RecNo, 'Bob' as Who, 'New' as type
UNION ALL SELECT 1,   2,   'Bob','Open'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,   3,   'Bob','Assign'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,   4,   'Sarah','Add'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,   5,   'Bob','Add'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,   6,   'Bob','Close'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,   1,   'John','New'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,   2,   'John','Open'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,   3,   'John','Assign'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,   4,   'Bob','Assign'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,   5,   'Sarah','Add'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,   6,   'Sarah','Close'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,   1,   'Sarah','New'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,   2,   'Sarah','Open'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,   3,   'Sarah','Assign'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,   4,   'Sarah','Close')
, GetTheMin AS (
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by recno) row,
    ID,
    RecNo,
    Who,
    type

FROM 
    INCIDENTS_H
WHERE
    type = 'Assign'
)
SELECT Who,
COUNT(ID)
FROM GetTheMin
WHERE
    row = 1
GROUP BY 
    who
```

OR you can use CROSS Apply

```
SELECT 
    who,
    COUNT(id) id
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
    MinValues.*
FROM
    INCIDENTS_H h
    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 *
                 FROM INCIDENTS_H h2
                 WHERE h.id = h2.id
                ORDER BY ID, RecNo asc) MinValues) getTheMin
GROUP BY WHO
```

Or you can use Min which uses standard SQL John Fisher's answer demonstrates

Comment: Hi. The first version implies that you enter all of the data again manually or am I missing something? The 2nd version gives an error when I run it saying that I am using the wrong syntax near 'apply (select Top 1 *'

Comment: @Andy The Common table expression INCIDENTS_H is so I can create a stand alone demonstration. Not just for your purposes but for anyone that might come along later. I didn't mean for you to take as that what your solution would include. To use the second example directly you need to still use the CTE I set up.

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do it:

```
SELECT IH.WHO, COUNT(IH.ID)
FROM INCIDENTS_H IH
JOIN (
  SELECT ID, MIN([Rec No]) [Rec No] 
  FROM INCIDENTS_H
  WHERE ([Type] = 'Assign')
  GROUP BY ID
 ) IH2
 ON IH2.ID = IH.ID AND IH2.[Rec No] = IH.[Rec No]
GROUP BY IH.WHO
```

Comment: Hi John. That works great, thanks. One more thing however - if i now need to add another criteria from a different table, how would I do that. I also need to limit the range by date, but the date is stored in a different table called 'incident' How could i limit the data by using incidents.addeddate

Comment: @Andy: It's hard to tell the right way without knowing the way the tables join together.  But, you should be able to figure it out.  You either join to the sub-select or to the main select, then update the Where clause on the select you joined to.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a view of everything in the table which should match your "first assign" requirement:

```
select a.*
from Table.INCIDENTS_H a
inner join
(select ID, min([Rec No]) [Rec No] from Table.INCIDENTS_H where Type = 'Assign' group by ID) b
on a.ID = b.ID and a.[Rec No] = b.[Rec No]
```

Result:

```
ID  Rec No  Who Type
1   3   Bob Assign
2   3   John    Assign
3   3   Sarah   Assign
```

Comment: I get an error saying check syntax to use near '[Recno]) [recno] from incidents_h where type = 'Assign'

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
  (select
     id, rec_no, who
   from
     operation_history
   where
     type = 'Assign'
   order by rec_no asc) table_alias
group by
  id
order by id asc
```

**Tested and here are the results:**

```
id  rec_no  who
1      3    Bob
2      3    John
3      3    Sarah
```

*(Code not specific to SQL Server)*

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for the response. I tried this and got 'Could not add the table '(select'. Is this because I only have read access to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query with virtual test data that were mentioned in the original post:

```
with T (ID,  RecNo,  Who, Type) as
(   
select 1,   1,   'Bob',     'New'   union all
select 1,   2,   'Bob',     'open'  union all
select 1,   3,   'Bob',     'Assign' union all
select 1,   4,   'Sarah',   'Add'   union all
select 1,   5,   'Bob',     'Add'   union all
select 1,   6,   'Bob',     'Close' union all
select 2,   1,   'John',    'New'   union all
select 2,   2,   'John',    'Open'  union all
select 2,   3,   'John',    'Assign' union all
select 2,   4,   'Bob',     'Assign' union all
select 2,   5,   'Sarah',   'Add'   union all
select 2,   6,   'Sarah',   'Close' union all
select 3,   1,   'Sarah',   'New'   union all
select 3,   2,   'Sarah',   'Open'  union all
select 3,   3,   'Sarah',   'Assign' union all
select 3,   4,   'Sarah',   'Close'
)

select top 1 with ties * 
from T
where Type = 'Assign'
order by row_number() over(partition by ID order by RecNo)
```

The "select" statement that can be applied to the real situation from the question might look like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
    IH.ID, IH.[Rec No], IH.WHO, IH.TYPE
FROM Table.INCIDENTS_H IH
WHERE IH.TYPE = 'Assign'
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IH.ID ORDER BY IH.[Rec No]);
```

Comment: Hi. This implies that you enter all of the data again manually or am I missing something? I just need to read the data out that is already in there.

Comment: In the first piece of code before final "select" there are just virtual data for test. I've inserted the real "select" for your real table in the second part of my post. :^)